# Fetch data from more than one tables using Group By

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join, group-by

I am using three tables in a PostgreSql database as:

```
Customer(Id, Name, City),
Product(Id, Name, Price),
Orders(Customer_Id, Product_Id, Date)
```

and I want to execute a query to get from them "the customers that have have ordered at least two different products alnong with the products". The query I write is:

```
select c.*, p.*
from customer c
join orders o on o.customer_id = c.id
join product p on p.id = o.product_id
group by (c.id)
having count(distinct o.product_id)>=2
```

It throws the error:

"column "p.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: `select c.*, p.*`".

However if I remove the the p.* from select statement (assuming that I one does not want the products, only the customers), it runs fine. How can I get the products as well?

**Update:** Having ordered two or more products, a customer must appear on the output as many times as its product he has ordered. I want as output a table with 5 columns:

```
Cust ID | Cust Name | Cust City | Prod ID | Prod Name | Prod Price
```

Is it possible in SQL given that `group by` should be used? Shoul it be used on more than one columns on different tables?

Comment: Can you post desired output?

Comment: please provide good information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use following query for this question -

```
SELECT C1.*, p1.*
  FROM Customer C1
  JOIN Orders O1 ON O1.Customer_Id = C1.Id
  JOIN Product P1 ON P1.Id = O1.Product_Id
 WHERE C1.Id IN (SELECT c.Id
                   FROM Customer c
                   JOIN Orders o ON o.Customer_Id = c.Id
                  GROUP BY (c.Id)
                 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT o.Product_Id) >= 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this out  :

SELECT distinct c.* ,p.* 
FROM Customer c 
JOIN 
   (SELECT o.customer_id cid
     FROM Product P 
     JOIN Orders o 
     ON p.id= o.product_id 
     GROUP BY o.customer_id 
     HAVING COUNT(distinct o.product_id)>=2) cp 
ON c.id =cp.cid 
JOIN Orders o  
on c.id=o.customer_id 
JOIN Product p 
ON o.product_id =p.id

I hope it solves your problem.